# Parse JSON to table (Wordpress)

Tags: json, wordpress, parsing, xml-parsing

I am looking at parsing some data from JSON and or XML into a table.

I am looking for someone to help me with the basics of this.  I need to parse multiple items form the JSON or XML into the table.  Below I  give my JSON example:

```
{"appartments":[{"aptnum":"199","design":"open","sqft":"1200","extras":"covered parking","pool":"yes","moveinDate":"2019-01-01 13:12:01","link":"https:\/\/www.demoapts.com\/demo\/199"},{"aptnum":"223","design":"Built Already","sqft":"1800","extras":"covered parking","pool":"yes","moveinDate":"2018-05-09 00:12:01","link":"https:\/\/www.demoapts.com\/demo\/223"}]
```

What I need help with is parsing this data to a html/Wordpress table.

I also am using a special type of button but I think I have that figured out if I can learn how to parse the data correctly.

I am hoping some of you can help me and point me in the right direction.  I have searched on Google and I have only found examples of parsing one item from the JSON.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example on how you can parse this JSON structure into a table

```
<?php
    $data = json_decode('{"appartments":[{"aptnum":"199","design":"open","sqft":"1200","extras":"covered parking","pool":"yes","moveinDate":"2019-01-01 13:12:01","link":"https:\/\/www.demoapts.com\/demo\/199"},{"aptnum":"223","design":"Built Already","sqft":"1800","extras":"covered parking","pool":"yes","moveinDate":"2018-05-09 00:12:01","link":"https:\/\/www.demoapts.com\/demo\/223"}]}');

    // Convert JSON string into a PHP object.
    $appartments = $data->appartments;

    echo('<table>');
    if(!empty($appartments)){
        echo('<thead><tr>');
        // Using the first object to print column names.
        foreach($appartments[0] as $key => $value){
            echo('<th>' . $key . '</th>');   
        }
        echo('</tr></thead>');

        echo('<tbody>');
        // Iterate through all appartments and print them as table cells.
        foreach($appartments as $appartment){
            echo('<tr>');
            foreach($appartment as $key => $value){
                echo('<td>' . $value . '</td>');   
            }
            echo('</tr>');
        }

    echo('</tbody></table>');
    }
?>
```

Comment: Hans  Thank you for that.  The json is in a url.  Will the same way work with a url that would have over items like what i showed in the example for the json code?

Comment: You can use the function `file_get_contents()` to get the content from a file or URL. You can add a new line at the beginning of my example where you first load the JSON data `$json = file_get_contents('url-to-json-source-here');`, and then convert it using `$data = json_decode($json);`. It should work fine with any items, as long as the items in the array have the same structure, otherwise the table will likely break.